# Ubuntu 20.04 how to remove duplicate packages after upgrade

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, system-monitor, gnome-calculator, character-set

I noticed that in My Ubuntu 20.04, I have some duplicate packages (from Ubuntu 18.04): Calculator, System monitor, etc. For instance, when I search for System monitor, here is the result:

[image]

In addition, the old packages appear with garbled-characters, when I open the old version it appears as follows:

[image]

However, the versions from Ubuntu 20.04 show up properly without that issue.

How can I get rid of those duplicated packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those packages are duplicated because in Ubuntu 18.04 they were installed as snap packages, but in Ubuntu 20.04 they are installed as deb packages.

Just open the terminal and run the following commands to remove all duplicated packages:

```
sudo snap remove --purge gnome-calculator
sudo snap remove --purge gnome-characters
sudo snap remove --purge gnome-logs
sudo snap remove --purge gnome-system-monitor
```

Comment: You are right. I've tried to remove them in a single go but snap complains: `error: a single snap name is needed to specify options`

Comment: @Navaro Sorry about that. I updated the answer. Thanks for your feedback.